# A permutation problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Consider all the permutations of the digits $1, 2, \dots, 9$. Find the number
of permutations each of which satisfies all of the following:

1. the sum of the digits lying between 1 and 2 (including 1 and 2)
   is 12
2. the sum of the digits lying between 2 and 3 (including 2 and 3)
   is 23
3. the sum of the digits lying between 3 and 4 (including 3 and 4)
   is 34, and
4. the sum of the digits lying between 4 and 5 (including 4 and 5)
   is 45.

How to solve such problems?

Answer (score 1):

$\{4,5\}$ are sure the first and the last elements. You have the template for permutation:

$$4*******5$$ The sum between $3$ and $4$ is $(34-3-4)=27$. Note that $1$ and $2$ are both between  $3$ to $4$. Then you have the only place to set $3$:
$$4*****365$$
The sum of the numbers which are not chosen yet is $27$. You should reach the sum of $(23-2-3)=18$ between $2$ and $3$. And $(12-1-2)=9$. Again, the only way, because $1$ should be between of $2$ and $3$:
$$472***365$$
Then
$$472918365$$
So there are 2 combinations: $472918365$ and $563819274$.